# How can I make yarn visuals similar to those in "Kirby's Epic Yarn"?

Tags: models, graphic-effects, modelling-techniques

I'd like to know how I can achieve the effect seen in Kirby's Epic Yarn:

[image]

All characters use "yarn" as outline which moves to simulate movement etc.

How can such an effect be achieved? Could one use 3D-Models with animation? Or 2D?

I have not yet committed to a specific engine or framework, so answers can make use of any tools.

Comment: If you ever find yourself stuck, maybe searching for how "crayon physics" games were drawn could give you a tip. Nintendo tends to be shy on such details, but indie devs like to share a tip or two.